# Azure Service Bus Queue client-side durability

Tags: azureservicebus

When using Brokered Messaging for the Service Bus Queue, I understand that cloud queue itself is durable. Does it also affects the client-side?

For example when I send the message to the queue, should I manually handle situation when transaction will be rejected either due to connection loss throttling issue, or it will be automatically persisted somewhere on the client and resend later?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "automatic" caching or storage of messages in the Service Bus `QueueClient` object or library. If the call to `QueueClient.Send(message)` succeeds without exceptions then the message is guaranteed to be durable stored. If an exception is raised then it indicates a failure (due to connectivity/throttling etc.). If you want to make your client resilient to connection drops etc. you may consider using a local queue like MSMQ in case a message send fails. We have a sample available that show how to transfer messages between MSMQ and Service Bus Queue: 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Brokered-Messaging-MSMQ-a31c6644